# In Java, is there a way I could go from JSONObject to JSONStringer, or vice versa?

Tags: java, json

I'm a bit confused as to how I can get around what seem to be some core limitations with the JSONStringer class. I understand that JSONStringer is meant to chain together JSON rather than create it fully-formed, but in the case that a function only returns a JSONStringer, I find my hands pretty tied. I'd like to do one of the following--

1. Append to the existing structure--see below. The first top-level object(), all keys/values therein and endObject() are within a method's scope, so how could I modify the JSONStringer after the fact? Trying to add the second obect() gets me a JSONException: Misplaced object.

   ```
       JSONStringer json = new JSONStringer();
       json.object();
       json.key("stuff").value("1")
               .key("name").value("2")
               .key("type_name").value("3")
               .key("type").value("4");
       json.endObject();

       json.object().key("hi").value("hi2").endObject();
   ```
2. Modify the existing structure, I.E. add another key inside of `json` above after it's returned from a method.
3. Create a JSONStringer from arbitrary JSON. I know this is what JSONObject is supposed to be for, but it's frustrating that there's no way to move between the two, especially when both amount to fancy structured wrappers for a String!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are much better solutions, but at least you have two choices:

1.after building *json* object inside a method which calls `JSONString.endObject();` you can use `JSONObject` class to add other key/values or modify existing ones:

```
    JSONStringer json = new JSONStringer();

    json.object();
    json.key("stuff").value("1")
            .key("name").value("2")
            .key("type_name").value("3")
            .key("type").value("4");
    json.endObject();

    //after calling the method which returns a jsonobject like above:
    JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(json.toString());
    jo.put("hi", "hi2");
```

2.don't call `endObject()` inside your method and do it after all operations:

```
public JSONStringer build() {
    JSONStringer json = new JSONStringer();

    json.object();
    json.key("stuff").value("1")
            .key("name").value("2")
            .key("type_name").value("3")
            .key("type").value("4");
    return json ;
}
//in the other place when calling above method, say:
    JSONStringer json=build();
    json.key("hi").value("hi2");
    json.endObject();
    System.out.println(json.toString());
```